# custom 404 - would this work?

Tags: asp-classic, http-status-code-404

Is this custom 404 page supposed to work?  It was created by another developer...
Running IIS7

```
    <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>

<%
 strQString=lcase(Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING"))
 If (Len(strQString)>4) Then
  strURL=Right(strQString,Len(strQString)-4)
  If (instr(lcase(strQString),"www")>1) then
   strURL = Replace(lcase(strURL),"www","www2")
  Else
   strURL = Replace(lcase(strURL),"http://","http://www2.")
  End If
 End If
%>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="3;URL=<%=strURL%>">
<style>
BODY{
 color: black;
 font-family: Arial;
 text-align: center;
 }
H1{font-size: 16px;}
H2{font-size: 12px;}
</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<img src="http://example.ca/_bin/images/logo.jpg"/>
<H1><%=Replace(strQString,"404;","")%> -  cannot be found.</H1>
<H2> Attempting to redirect to <a href="<%=strURL%>"><%=strURL%></a> ...</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

These kind of things are not recommended if you care about SEO.
Either fix the problem for 500 errors or put a 301 PERMANENT REDIRECT for 404 errors but dynamic redirects are not going to be seen favorably by robots..

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  We are not worried about robots as the subfolders are only for existing links to web apps we host for our employees.